# How to move values between columns with condition

Tags: r

I want to move value from the column II to the column I only when rows on the column I show NA.

This is the data.frame :

```
id <- c("A","B","C","D", "E","F","G")
I <- c("NA","NA","NA","10","20","NA","30")
II <- c("3","4","5","6","7", "8", "8")
df <- data.frame(id, I, II)
```

The expected result would be like this :

```
id <- c("A","B","C","D", "E","F","G")
I <- c("NA","NA","NA","10","20","NA","30")
II <- c("3","4","5","6","7", "8", "8")
III <- c("3","4","5","10","20", "8", "30")
df <- data.frame(id, I, II,III)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a simple `coalesce` after converting the quoted "NA" to actual unquoted `NA` in a single line

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
            mutate(III = coalesce(na_if(I, "NA"), II))
df1
#   id    I II III
#1  A <NA>  3   3
#2  B <NA>  4   4
#3  C <NA>  5   5
#4  D   10  6  10
#5  E   20  7  20
#6  F <NA>  8   8
#7  G   30  8  30
```

---

Or using `base R`, change the "NA" to `NA`, create a logical vector based on the presence of `NA` elements in 'I' to change the values of 'III' (after assigning the values of 'II'

```
df$I[df$I == "NA"] <- NA
df$III <- df$II
df$III[!is.na(df$I)]  <- df$I[!is.na(df$I)]
```

---

Or with `ifelse`

```
df$III <- with(df, ifelse(I == "NA", II, I))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, III = ifelse(I == 'NA', II, I))

#  id  I II III
#1  A NA  3   3
#2  B NA  4   4
#3  C NA  5   5
#4  D 10  6  10
#5  E 20  7  20
#6  F NA  8   8
#7  G 30  8  30
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop in Base R will get this done

```
III = 0

for (i in 1:length(id)){
  if (I[i] == "NA"){
    III[i] = II[i]} else {
      III[i] = I[i]}
}

df = data.frame(id, I, II, III)
```